# How to make let the user select the location of the file which needs to be saved?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file

How do I make [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzSCU.png)

When the user clicks to save the file an intent will get activated and tell the user where he wants to save that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Storage Access Framework to do exactly this. There is a pretty good description in the [Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#create-file), so I just provide the simplest  sample right here:

```
const val CREATE_FILE = 1
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
    addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
}
startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE)
```